# How to use GITHUB_TOKEN to install private go packages

Tags: git, go, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

In our organization, we have several private Go packages present in private GitHub repositories.

In the project I'm currently working on, I make use of some of these packages. I'm writing a GitHub action to perform the testing, and I need to set it up so it can download those private packages.

In the script that runs the tests, before beginning the tests I have this line:

```bash
git config --global "url.https://${GH_TOKEN}@github.com/.insteadOf" https://github.com/
```

This instructs Git to use the provided token to perform authentication with GitHub and it's sufficient for Go to clone the repos and find the sources.

In the GHA workflow file, I use a step like this:

```yaml
      - name: Run tests
        run: scripts/run-tests.sh
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.MY_GH_TOKEN }}
```

, where `MY_GH_TOKEN` is a repository secret with my PAT. This works well.

I would like to know if I can replace my PAT with `GITHUB_TOKEN`. If I do it just like that, it does not work.

```yaml
      - name: Run tests
        run: scripts/run-tests.sh
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

It fails with error messages such as:

```
github.com/MyOrg/my-repo@v0.0.0-20240201134851-adbfcc688eba: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /root/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/
exit status 128:
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://***@github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

It's the signal that the token I provided does not have sufficient permissions to clone a repo, I think. However, I could not find in the [official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication), nor anywhere else, how to allow the automatically generated token to clone a private repo. Is it even possible, or am I stuck with using a PAT?

Why am I trying to get rid of the PAT? To have one less token to maintain (it needs to be changed at least once a year) and protect (however secure the GitHub credentials manager is, it's one more piece of information that could give access to our code and infrastructure). (Also, to have one less thing to give a name to...)

Comment: I don't think there's a way around using a PAT.